# do while loop with condition in header and footer

Tags: java

My compiler eats this:

```
    do while (condition1) {
        // do something
    } while (condition2);
```

Oracle does not explicitly say it is possible http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html, but my compiler accepts the two conditions. Does this actually work or is there a reason why I cannot do this?

The construct makes perfect sense as often we have two conditions, like a counter and an object, where only one of these conditions needs to be checked right away when entering the loop.

I know that I could use an if statement and break; - I just wanted to learn if there is a reason why I should not use the two criteria.

Comment: This is not a double-condition `while`, they are two separated `while` loops.

Comment: @Aeshang The syntax is perfectly fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have there is

```
do {
  while (condition1) {
    // do something
  }
} while (condition2);
```

So the `do something` is executed repeatedly as long as `condition1` holds, and then the whole loop is launched again while `condition2` holds.

Answer (score 4):

> Oracle does not explicitly say it is possible

In fact, it isn't possible.

Your example is not a double criteria while loop.

It's translated to this:

```
do {
    while (condition1) {
        // do something
    } 
} while (condition2);
```

Answer (score 0):

why not do:

```
if(condition1) {
  do {
    // your code here
  } while (condition1 && condition2)
}
```

Not a huge fan of your double condition because it's confusing

Answer (score 0):

this code construct works actually, Java compiler runs it with no error or exception.

Logic behind it is, these loops are nested. The while loop is nested in do-while.

and here java compiler takes while loop inside the do-while body as just single line statement, which can be written without enclosing between pair of braces.

equivalent to

```
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
            for(int j = 0 ; j<10; j++){
                     //statements;
            }
```

or

```
     while(condition)
            for(int j = 0 ; j<10; j++){
                     //statements;
            }
```

in given code construct pair of braces makes the body of while loop, instead of body of outer do-while loop, as in for loop construct the pair of braces makes the body of inner for loop.

```
     do while (condition1) {
              // do something
              } while (condition2);
```

this is valid code construct.